# Does Magento send order cancellation emails?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, email, email-templates

I have been placing and canceling orders all day without receiving any cancellation confirmation emails and thought maybe Magento 1.7 doesn't support this feature!?!

If anyone has had the requirement to send emails depending on changed order states please let me know if you are able to share a solution please (in particular order cancellation email)...

Thanks in advance guys!

Here's my Observer.php

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', '1');
class Namespace_Customail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED);
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }

    private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
    {
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was cancelled');

        // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
        $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
    }
}
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Customail>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Customail>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <customail>
                <class>Namespace_Customail</class>
            </customail>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <mail_status_change>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>customail/observer</class>
                        <method>invoicedStatusChange</method>
                    </mail_status_change>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
        <template>
            <email>
                <custom_order_tpl module="Namespace_Customail">
                    <label>Status Mail Invoice</label>
                    <file>statusmail_processing.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </custom_order_tpl>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento *does* send a number of transactional emails, including cancellation (e.g. order status change); the only issue with a cancellation email, requires the customer service agent cancelling to click "Notify Customer". You can edit this to be the default.

To enable emails on order comments, go to `System > Config > Sales Emails` and make sure it's enabled:

[image]

The email template is located in `app/locale/[en_US]/template/email/sales/order_update.html` by default, replacing `en_US` with your actual locale, of course, if you're using another language pack.

This line:

```
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    Your order # {{var order.increment_id}} has been <br/>
    <strong>{{var order.getStatusLabel()}}</strong>.
</p>
```

Provides the output for the 'status' update. You can create custom styling with control-flow statements like `if` or `depends`:

```
<p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
    Your order # {{var order.increment_id}} has been <br/>
    {{if order.getStatusLabel()=='canceled'}}
        <strong>CANCELED - THERE, ARE YOU HAPPY?!</strong>
    {{else}}
        {{var order.getStatusLabel()}}.
    {{/if}}
</p>
```

Comment: Hey Phillip, I don't think you can do a condition as in your example on the label.  At least not anymore.  Would be nice though!

Answer (score 6):

Magento does not send an e-mail when the order is canceled.
But there is an event `order_cancel_after`, triggered  each time you cancel an order. You can use that one to send an e-mail to your customers.
You can also use the `sales_order_save_after`for a general case. Check the difference between `$order->getState()` and `$origData = $order->getOrigData(); $origData['state']` to see the state changing and take the appropriate action.

Comment: I've set about writing a quick module to do this in 1.7 but I get a black page on the transactional emails page... Am I using the wrong event?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong, but you can follow the steps presented here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429 and you should figure it out.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work finally but it turned out that Magento will send a Cancellation confirmation email from the Sales_Order_View page just be sure to tick the box "notify custom" and "visible on frontend" then click submit after you have cancelled the order. I was trying to send an email if the order is cancelled from the Grid.

Comment: The e-mail you are talking about is actually the 'order update' e-mail. It is sent to the customer each time you update something to the order and you choose to notify  the customer. But when actually canceling the order nothing triggers an email sending to the customer.

Comment: Agree, I'm still working on my module and will post back if I get it to work from the Grid.