# Send Order cancel email in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email, sales-order, email-templates

We are using Magento 1.9.1 in my website i tried to send cancel order email but i am not able to send mail to customer. How to send mail to particular customer?

Comment: check answer here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/does-magento-send-order-cancellation-emails

Comment: I tried else Condition not working

Comment: you can use *order_cancel_after* event to fire cancel email to customer.

Comment: Can you please give a code i am new from magento

Comment: are you send order cancel email admin end?

Comment: yes while click cancel i need to send mail to customer

Comment: @MagentoDev check here. already code available here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/send-email-after-order-is-canceled

Comment: Even i tried this also but not working

Comment: Open file app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php

Comment: find function cancelAction() and add code $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null); after $order->cancel()
                    ->save();

Comment: and check again it is working or not

Comment: if it working then override controller action in core to local

Comment: Ok i will check it

Comment: @Abdul it's working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34189/discussion-between-abdul-and-magento-dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace code in file `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\OrderController.php`

**From**

```
public function cancelAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->cancel()
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order has been cancelled.')
            );
        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been cancelled.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }
}
```

**To**

```
public function cancelAction()
    {
        if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
            try {
                $order->cancel()
                    ->save();
                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order has been cancelled.')
                );
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order has not been cancelled.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** if it working then override controller action in core to local